# How do make images level in PowerPoint 2010

Tags: images, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I need to achieve that 20 images are at the same level in PowerPoint without adjusting each of them. How do I do this?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are looking for where the "Align left" / "Align Top" etc. functions have gone which used to be on the "Drawing" Toolbar under "Draw/Align or Distribute" in PowerPoint 2003?

Comment: Yes, that is correct!

Comment: please accept Jonas's answer if it worked for you to close out the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated answer**

As discussed in the comments above the option you are looking for is called "Align left" / "Align Top". In **PowerPoint 2010**, you need to select all images and then go to

`Picture Tools | Format | Arrange | Align | Align Left`, as shown here:

[image]

In PowerPoint 2003 it can be found on the "Drawing" Toolbar under "Draw/Align or Distribute". If you knew where to find it in 2003, to find out where it went in PP2010 have a look at the page

[Learn where menu and toolbar commands are in Office 2010 and related products](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/learn-where-menu-and-toolbar-commands-are-in-office-2010-and-related-products-HA101794130.aspx)

The Excel2010 spreadsheet linked there contains the answer:

[A printable list of Office 2010 commands and buttons](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/CL101817133.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA101794130).

Comment: Why didn't you post your comment above as an answer? This one here is not very useful and at least having the options for PowerPoint 2003 would be an answer ;)

Comment: Agreed - I'll rewrite the answer to include the information from my comment above.